# MVVM Change label foreground based on the value of the labels content

Tags: mvvm

The content of my labels are bound to the VM and based on calculations will either be negative or positive. If they are positive I want the foreground to be a certain color and different color if they are negative. Should I just handle all this in the VM by binding the labels' foreground? There are only 4 labels btw.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would let the View handle how it displays the label. In my opinion, I would keep this color logic out of the ViewModel - as it should only handle business rules and such and not worry about how items are displayed.

XAML:

```
<sdk:Label Content="{Binding NumericValue}" Foreground="{Binding NumericValue, Converter={StaticResource numToColor}}" />
```

View Model:

```
private decimal _numValue = -1;
public decimal NumericValue
{
    get { return _numValue; }
    set
    {
    _numValue = value;
    RaisePropertyChanged("NumericValue");
    }
}
```

The Converter

```
public class NumberToColorConverter : IValueConverter
{
    #region IValueConverter Members

    public object Convert(object value, System.Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
            if (value == null || !(value is decimal))
                return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);

            var dValue = System.Convert.ToDecimal(value);
            if (dValue < 0)
                return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
            else
                return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, System.Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to assume this is Silverlight or WPF

You need to create a ValueConverter.  To do this you will need to create a new class that 
implements the `IValueConverter` interface.  The MSDN has a detailed explanation on how to do this.

Silverlight 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter%28v=VS.95%29.aspx

WPF 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter%28v=VS.100%29.aspx